# How to plot two dataframes in the same area chart and difference them by dark and light colors?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, multi-index

I have two dataframes, let's say the first one corresponds to operational power plants and the second one to pipeline power plants. I want to plot both in the same area chart. They should be differenced by dark and light colors as the plots below. I have tried to insert a column into each dataframe and set it as an index (besides Country and fuel). I could't either set a new columns as an index or plot the dataframes in the same plot. I really appreciate some idea to execute that.

```
df1
              2010  2020  2030  2040  2050  
Country  Fuel
A        Gas   100   110   120   130   140
         Coal  100   110   120   130   140 
df2
              2010  2020  2030  2040  2050  
Country  Fuel
A        Gas   100   110   120   130   140
         Coal  100   110   120   130   140
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find that hierarchical indexes get in the way for certain tasks (like this one) and it is better to do all of the manipulation on a flat dataframe. In the steps below, I use `reset_index` to turn the index levels into ordinary columns, and then `set_index` to put them back again in preparation for the plotting step.

```
# reset the indexes, and add a new column to both dataframes
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1['Plant Type'] = 'Operational'

df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2['Plant Type'] = 'Pipeline'

# concatenate the two dataframes
df_combined = pd.concat([df1, df2])

# set the index back to how it was, but also include the new column, and then plot
df_combined.set_index(['Plant Type', 'Country', 'Fuel']).plot.area()
```

Comment: I added the results I got based on your commentaries in my question. I am still have got a problem in the plot.